# Invalid Frame when debugging with PyDev and Eclipse

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

When I run a Django project in debug mode with Eclipse (and PyDev plugin) it stops in all the breakpoints correctly and I can inspect all the values of the environment variables, but when I try to write whatever in the console I get this error and it doesn't print anything else:

```
[Invalid Frame]: Please select frame to connect the console.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Humm, turns out this was a bug when debugging multiple processes in PyDev. I just fixed it in https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/e13fd81fe87365be54aed8405741f84df90f2fca.

It should be released on PyDev 4.5.0. In the meanwhile, as a workaround to have a console with such a connection you can right-click the stack (in the debug view) and select PyDev > Debug Console -- by doing so, you'll have an interactive console with a proper connection to that frame.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. For now it is enough for me. I will update PyDev as soon as I can. By the way, good job!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem while running on Windows 7 with Eclipse, nano and Pydev 5.2.

`PYTHONPATH` was set in Eclipse. But I expected that the variable was automatically set in the environment variables. But it's not the case.

I corrected it by following these steps:

1. Went to **Advanced System Settings** in `Control Panel/All Control Panel Items/System/`.
2. Entered into Environment Variables.
3. Added `%PYTHONPATH%` and the value of e.g. `E:\blender-2.77-windows64\doc\python_api\pypredef;` (Or where you have your python installation).
4. Added this variable to my system's `PATH` variable